# The program does not have the required permissions to erase the unused space on disk

Tags: eraser

I am trying to use [Heidi Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie) (I guess it's just called Eraser these days) to wipe unused disk space on a drive. No matter what I do, I get the following error message:

> The program does not have the required permissions to erase the unused
>   space on disk. Run the program as an administrator and retry the
>   operation.

I ran Eraser as administrator and I still get the error. I’ve tried taking ownership of the drive and it still doesn't work. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone on the [Eraser forums](http://eraser.heidi.ie/forum/) pointed out that you need to close the running instance of Eraser in the system tray and then rerun it as administrator. This worked for me.